Mediator analysis after Weightthem
After computing the Average Treatment Effect (ATE) for my entire population using Weightthem, I wanted to evaluate whether the treatment effect differs across levels of the distance from the metastasis treated (≤10mm or >10mm). To achieve this, I first performed Inverse Probability Weighting (IPW) between groups and checked the balance:
subgroups_formula <- Treatment_type_tumor_near_gallbladder ~ age_binary + sex + bmi_binary + ASA_binary + comorbidities_Major + Systemic_treatment_prior_local_treatment + Segments_treated_per_session_binned + Metastasis_size_at_treatment_mm + stage_binary + Metastasis_location_superficial + min_distance_gallblad_mm_binary

# Perform IPW in each imputed dataset
w.out_model1_subgroups_ATE <- weightthem(subgroups_formula, 
data = new_amcore_imputed, 
method = "cbps",  # ebal, cbps, glm, gbm, energy, OptWeight, IPT, npcbps
estimand =  "ATE",
criterion = "smd.mean", # minimizes the average absolute standard mean difference among the covariates between treatment groups.
link = "logit",   # probit, logit, cloglog, br.probit, br.logit, br.cloglog
by = "min_distance_gallblad_mm_binary"
)

#Checking balance before and after matching:
bal.tab(w.out_model1_subgroups_ATE, 
    data = new_amcore_imputed, 
    s.d.denom = "pooled", 
    m.threshold = 0.1, 
    #v.threshold = 2, 
    imp.fun ='max', 
    un = TRUE, 
    abs = TRUE,
    binary = "std",
    cluster = "min_distance_gallblad_mm_binary") # un = TRUE

After achieving good balance within clusters, I computed the ATE within each cluster:
# PS weighting for the ATE with logistic regression PS
results_all <- with(w.out_model1_subgroups_ATE, 
  WeightIt::glm_weightit(new_formula, family = quasibinomial, weightit = w.out_model1_subgroups_ATE), cluster = FALSE)

# Compute the ATE on RISK RATIO SCALE
ATE_all <- lapply(results_all$analyses, function(fit) {
    marginaleffects::avg_comparisons(fit, variables = "Treatment_type_tumor_near_gallbladder",
        comparison = "lnratioavg",
        by = "min_distance_gallblad_mm_binary",
        transform = "exp") 
    })

# Combine results into one data frame
ATE_combined <- bind_rows(ATE_all, .id = "imputation_id")

# Number of imputations
M <- length(unique(ATE_combined$imputation_id))

# Pooled ATE applying Rubin's rules
ATE_pooled <- ATE_combined %>%
  dplyr::group_by(term, contrast, min_distance_gallblad_mm_binary) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(
    # Pooled Estimate
    pooled_estimate = mean(estimate, na.rm = TRUE),
    
    # Between-Imputation Variance (B)
    between_variance = var(estimate, na.rm = TRUE),
    
    # Within-Imputation Variance (U)
    within_variance = mean((conf.high - conf.low)^2 / (2 * 1.96)^2, na.rm = TRUE),
    
    # Total Variance (T)
    total_variance = within_variance + (1 + 1 / M) * between_variance,
    
    # Standard Error (SE)
    pooled_se = sqrt(total_variance),
    
    # Confidence Intervals
    pooled_conf_low = pooled_estimate - 1.96 * pooled_se,
    pooled_conf_high = pooled_estimate + 1.96 * pooled_se,
    
    # (Optional) Pooled p-value
    pooled_p_value = mean(p.value, na.rm = TRUE),
    
    .groups = "drop"
  )

# Drop unuseful columns
ATE_pooled <- ATE_pooled %>%
  dplyr::select(-between_variance, -within_variance, -total_variance)

ATE_pooled %>%
  dplyr::mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ round(., digits = 3)))

Since mice::pool() does not seem to support the use of a by argument when computing the ATE with avg_comparisons, I implemented a custom version of Rubin’s rules. Using this approach, I obtained the following results:



Term
Contrast
min_distance_gallblad_mm_binary
Pooled Estimate
Pooled SE
Pooled Conf Low
Pooled Conf High
Pooled p-value




Treatment_type_tumor_near_gallbladder
ln(mean(MWA) / mean(Resection))
<=10mm
0.942
0.391
0.175
1.709
0.875


Treatment_type_tumor_near_gallbladder
ln(mean(MWA) / mean(Resection))
>10mm
0.421
0.165
0.097
0.745
0.017



Next, I compared effects between subgroups:
# Compute the ATE on RISK RATIO SCALE
ATE_all <- lapply(results_all$analyses, function(fit) {
    marginaleffects::avg_comparisons(fit, variables = "Treatment_type_tumor_near_gallbladder",
        by = "min_distance_gallblad_mm_binary",
        hypothesis = "pairwise") 
    })

# Combine results into one data frame
# Pool the results and summarize
ATE_results <- ATE_all |> mice::pool() |> summary(exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE) |> mutate(across(where(is.numeric), \(x) round(x, digits = 3)))

# Print the results
ATE_results

Output:



Term
Estimate
Std. Error
Statistic
DF
p-value
2.5 %
97.5 %




<=10mm - >10mm
1.404
0.248
1.368
4e+08
0.171
0.863
2.284



Is my approach correct? Is there an alternative way to perform a moderator analysis after using Weightthem? Why I can't use the mice::pool() method after computing the ATE on RR scale when the argument by is used?
Thank you in advance!
